# How to spyOn a service function within the link of a directive?

Tags: testing, service, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angularjs-service

I have a directive that uses a service function like so:

```
angular.module('testModule',
['serviceBeingUsed'])
.directive('testDirective', function(serviceBeingUsed) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'testTemplate.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            boundVar1: "="
        },
        link: function(scope) {

            scope.getRequiredData = function(data){

                //gether data using service
                serviceBeingUsed.fetchRequiredData(data).then(
                    function(result){
                        scope.requiredData = result;
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    };
});
```

In the above directive I inject the service I wish to use and this service function gets used within the scope function "getRequiredData()" which is inside the "link" of this directive.

I have my test suite set up like so:

```
describe('test suite', function () {

var scope,
    $rootScope,
    $compile,
    $q,
    element,
    isoScope,
    serviceBeingUsed;

beforeEach(module('testModule'));

beforeEach( inject( function(_$rootScope_,
                             _$q_,
                             _$compile_,
                             _serviceBeingUsed_) {

    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $compile = _$compile_;
    serviceBeingUsed = _serviceBeingUsed_;
    $q = _$q_;

    //This is where we create the directive and it's options.
    element = angular.element('<test-directive bound-var1="blabla"></test-directive>');

    //We create a new scope from the rootScope.
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    //Now we compile the HTML with the rootscope
    $compile(element)(scope);

    //digest the changes
    scope.$digest();

    //We retrieve the isolated scope scope of the directive 
    isoScope = element.isolateScope();

}));
```

Now I have a test which runs and passes wherby I can spyOn the isolated scope function "getRequiredData()", this test looks like so:

```
it('getRequiredData runs', inject(function () {
    spyOn(isoScope,"getRequiredData");
    isoScope.getRequiredData();

    expect(isoScope.getRequiredData).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

This proves that the link functions CAN be tested however when trying to test if the service function is called the test fails and I have no idea why, the test for the service looks like this:

```
it('serviceFunction runs', inject(function () {
    spyOn(serviceBeingUsed, "serviceFunction").and.callFake(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var data = "returnedDataDummy";

        deferred.resolve(data);
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    isoScope.getRequiredData();

    expect(serviceBeingUsed.serviceFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

How can I successfully test if the service function has been called here?

Comment: Could you please post what error do you get? For me, this line is a bit confusing `angular.module('testModule', ['serviceBeingUsed'])` - is your service also a module?
Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/215JhbUbhNqfaHQei2a5?p=preview)

Comment: the service is also a module which gets injected in the line     "angular.module('testModule', ['serviceBeingUsed'])"

Answer (score 1):

In writing this example I have solved my issue. In my actual code, inside the test "serviceFunction runs" I had also included a `spyOn(isoScope,"getRequiredData)"`

This has the effect of blocking the inner functionality of the function

```
getRequiredData()
```

which meant the the service function inside getRequiredData could never run.

To resolve this issue I needed to edit the spy for the outer function

from:

```
spyOn(isoScope,"getRequiredData");
```

to:

```
spyOn(isoScope,"getRequiredData").and.callThrough();
```

this simple change means that the function being spied on will also run its inner code and not just register that it has been called.

However one important lesson that I have learned is to not do too much inside each test and to separate the tests as much as possible.

So just to clarify, my **original test which failed** looked like this:

```
it('getRequiredData runs', inject(function () {
    spyOn(serviceBeingUsed, "serviceFunction").and.callFake(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var data = "returnedDataDummy";

        deferred.resolve(data);
        return deferred.promise;
    });
    spyOn(isoScope,"getRequiredData");

    isoScope.getRequiredData();

    expect(serviceBeingUsed.fetchRequiredData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(isoScope.getRequiredData).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

**the fix for this test which passes:**

```
it('getRequiredData runs', inject(function () {
        spyOn(serviceBeingUsed, "serviceFunction").and.callFake(function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var data = "returnedDataDummy";

            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        });
        spyOn(isoScope,"getRequiredData").and.callThrough();

        isoScope.getRequiredData();

        expect(serviceBeingUsed.fetchRequiredData).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(isoScope.getRequiredData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```